# How can I access console.log() from node application in ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, pm2, console.log

[Sample code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuoQy.png)

I have a node JS application, using express js as its framework, I integrated some APIs in my application, on my local before pushing to aws, and everything works fine, I get the required data I need from the various endpoints, however when I pushed to AWS, I couldn't get data from the endpoints I integrated, and the application works fine, so I have console.log in strategic places to debug into what could be the issue, unfortunately, I do not know where to view the logs. I use pm2 as the process manager and the application uses a reverse proxy NGINX.

PM2 logs does not give me the logs in the application, for example, console.log(response) in my code, I want to check what the response returns.

Comment: Have you tried view your app logs via AWS CloudWatch?

Comment: I couldn't generate a logs group for it, it was meant to be generated automatically after downloading, installing and enabling the cloud watch but it didn't, so what solved it for me was, i stoped running pm2, so i can see the logs normally on terminal